# Finding the complementry strand of DNA

Tags: python

I'm given the following DNA string:

```py
mydna = 'AGUGGCUAUUACUACAUGCCGAAGUUCCUUAAAUUUAACUUACCAGGCUUAACCGGAUGAUGAUUAUUAUUACCUUAAUUUUA'
```

How can I get the DNA string's complement?

Comment: How do you define "complementary strand"?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: `''.join([{"A":"U","U":"A","G":"C","C":"G"}[x] for x in mydna])`

Comment: And the letter "U" is not used with DNA.  That's an RNA letter, right?

Comment: Then, for the next time, @user18765994 , try first, post after, explain your problem in detail and don't ask for homeworks(even non-graded worksheets)\scripts, ask for a solution to a given problem.

Comment: @user18765994 I'm not being negative at all, I'm just saying that this isn't the right place to ask questions that way. You are also asking people to do your exercises (using ifs, using tuples as input values, and so on), if you skipped the class, I'm sure some of your friends took notes. From the perspective of people replying if a generalized version of the program works, the solution has been given, you should make it work (at minimum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No fancy stuff:

```
original_strand = 'AGUGGCUAUUACUACAUGCCGAAGUUCCUUAAAUUUAACUUACCAGGCUUAACCGGAUGAUGAUUAUUAUUACCUUAAUUUUA'
new_strand = ''

for char in original_strand: # for every character in the string...
    if char == 'A':
        replace_with = 'U'
    elif char == 'U':
        replace_with = 'A'
    elif char == 'C':
        replace_with = 'G'
    elif char == 'G':
        replace_with = 'C'

    new_strand += replace_with

print(new_strand)
```

Comment: wait this makes so much sense i had no idea how to go about using if/elif but this does make sense, thank you so much!

Comment: when i try to put this in, i'm getting an error on the final strand saying "'tuple' object is not callable" - could you explain what this means?

Comment: @user18765994 To me, this error indicates that you must have redefined the `print` function by mistake. Do you have `print = ...` anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans):

```py
translation = str.maketrans("AUCG", "UAGC")
print(mydna.translate(translation))
```

This outputs:

```py
UCACCGAUAAUGAUGUACGGCUUCAAGGAAUUUAAAUUGAAUGGUCCGAAUUGGCCUACUACUAAUAAUAAUGGAAUUAAAAU
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick one liner that does the job:

```py
''.join([{'A': 'U', 'U': 'A', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C'}[i.upper()] for i in mydna])
```

It iterates through every character in the original string and then replaces the values.

Comment: Well, we can't do your homework for you :), but you can use a loop to recreate the list comp